# sql: how to add int records of one table into another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, addition

I'm using microsoft sql server management studio 2008 and here is my problem
I have a view, that contains a column with distinct IDs and a column with "tempory" numbers for each ID (int datatype)
Besides this I have a table, with a cloumn for same matching ID's and a column with "sum" of numbers (int as well)

I need to write a procedure, that will add the numbers from the view to the sum column of the table, according to the IDs

How can I make it?

Comment: you need to update the table? or just a select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the update + join syntax

```
update T
set T.sum_column = T.sum_column + V.tempory
from TableA T
inner join ViewA V on T.id = V.id
```

Also after that you can place a WHERE clause to filter wich lines to update

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DistinctID, v.TemporaryNumber + o.SumNumber FROM ViewTable v JOIN OtherTable o ON v.DistinctID = o.DistinctID